# How can I run multiple python code on a windows 10 simultaniously?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, subprocess, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run 2 scrips simultaneously in python3 on my Windows 10, however the scripts runs consecutively (first one finished then second starts).

I have already tried to run them with both "&" and "&&" but to no avail. Here is my code:

```
import subprocess
import S1 #script 1 (it opens a chrome page with Selenium)
import S2 #script 2 (it opens a chrome page with Selenium)
subprocess.run("python S1 && python S2", shell=True)
```

I have also tried:

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Process

def script1():
    os.system("S1.py")
def script2():
    os.system("S2.py")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=script1)
    q = Process(target=script2)
    p.start()
    q.start()
    p.join()
    q.join()
```

But I got the same results and the scripts run consecutively.

How can I get to run both simultaneously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `.py` at the end of your file names in the subprocess command.

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.run("python S1.py && python S2.py", shell=True)
```

Comment: Hi @okawo, I tried that but it still finishes first the S1.py and after it start the S2.py, I'm trying to run them simultaneously.

Comment: You can try to use asyncio to run them at the same time